# Meteor not following link / Iron router does not re-render

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I'm having trouble with this strange behaviour. I have a simple link:

```
<a href="/page2/param">Link</a>
```

If I click on the link and then go back to the previous page, the same link doesn't work anymore. Googling around it seems to be caused by iron router not re-rendering the template, but I couldn't find a way to solve this.

Any hint?

Here is my `router.js`

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: "layout"
});
Router.route("/page1/:id", {
    name: "page1",
    template: "page1",
    yieldTemplates: {
        info: {
            to: "info"
        }
    },
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe("publish", {
            _id: this.params.id
        });
    }
});
Router.route("/page2/:id", {
    name: "page2",
    template: "page2",
    waitOn: function() {
        return Meteor.subscribe("publish", {
            _id: this.params.id
        });
    }
});
```

Here are my templates

```
<template name="layout">
    {{#if currentUser}}
        {{>yield region="info"}}
    {{/if}}
    {{> yield}}
</template>

<template name="info">
    <a href="/page2/{{id}}">
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
    </a>
</template>
```

Comment: You should be using `<a href={{pathFor 'page2' id='param'}}>link</a>` instead of hard-coding your link.  In regards to your question, what do you mean "it doesn't work anymore"? what does it do?

Comment: I am actually hardcoding only the page url because I know that's not gonna change but I guess to make it more flexible I could update that with your suggestion. Anyway, the issue is that the first time I load `page1` and I click on that link, I get redirected to `page2` correctly. If then I go back to `page1` (using the browser back button) the same link does not work anymore. However, if I analyse the code, the link is still correct.

Comment: Could you replicate it on meteorpad for us?

Comment: It seems like I can't... I've created this but it works as expected. http://meteorpad.com/pad/SqkLSz2hR9qk3w4r3/Leaderboard in my case though once I go back if I click on the button again nothing happens

Comment: Well it comes down to figuring out what is different between that and your project. What packages do you have installed? What version are you on?

Comment: Found it. Basicallt it was a bad event selector that was not enough specific and it was blocking the default behaviour (that is, follow the link). Weird though that the first time the page loads it works as expected